# tkinter: how to write a for loop to destroy a list of labels?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, tkinter, label, destroy

I am trying to remove these elements from the grid.  I was able to delete all of them by writing out one by one.  I then wrote a for loop to make it expandable, then I run into this error message.

```
"employee.destroy()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'destroy'"
```

This is part of a bigger program, but as much as I can reduce to the core problem, here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

labelemployee={}

class Application(ttk.Frame): #inherent from frame.

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg="LightBlue4")
        self.parent = parent
        self.Employees = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
        self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
        self.GUI()

    def GUI(self): #the function that runs all the GUI functions.
        self.buttons()
        self.create_grid()
        self.add_left_names()

    def remove(self):
        #labelemployee["A"].destroy()
        #labelemployee["B"].destroy()
        #labelemployee["C"].destroy()
        #labelemployee["D"].destroy()
        for employee in labelemployee:
            employee.destroy()

    def create_grid(self):
        for i in range (7):
             for j in range(7):
                self.label = tk.Label(self, relief="ridge", width=12, 
                       height=3)
                self.label.grid(row=i, column=j, sticky='nsew')

    def buttons(self):
        self.button=tk.Button(self, text="Clear", bg="salmon", command 
             = self.remove)
        self.button.grid(row=7, column=6, sticky='e')

    def add_left_names(self):
       #--------add in name labels on the side--------------        
        i=2
        for employee in self.Employees:
            self.label=tk.Label(self, text=employee ,  fg="red", 
               bg="snow")
            self.label.grid(row=i,column=0)
            labelemployee[employee]=self.label
            i +=1

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("class basic window")
    root.geometry("1000x500")
    root.config(background="LightBlue4")
    app = Application(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Please help me.  I think the problem is my for loop is stored a list, and I have a dictionary.  So, then I guess i don't know how to destroy labels in a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already figured out the issue in those comments !

You already know that `labelemployee` is a dictionary, so iterating over it will give you, by default, the keys of the dictionary. So `employee` will be strings like *A*, *B*... and so on. And destroying a string object will obviously give you an error. You need to destroy the corresponding tkinter widget. So for that, you should replace `employee.destroy()` with `labelemployee[employee].destroy()` in the for loop.

Comment: thanks for your help.  I was confused on how to code it.  I am getting it slowly.

Comment: would I trouble you to help me with https://stackoverflow.com/q/53358873/5989438 since you helped me with this one.    It does not look like anyone is helping me.  I really appreciate it.