# python, tkinter, how to destroy labels in two different tabs with for loop?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tabs, label, destroy

Thanks to @Miraj50 that helped me with the .destroy() 
[tkinter: how to write a for loop to destroy a list of labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53349476/5989438)  For the next stage, I am trying to destroy the labels in both tabs. I knew how to share the same list to different tabs, but I don't know how to "link" them to the tabs.  With my limited knowledge I tried

```
def remove(self, name):
    for name in tabs[name]:
        for employee in labelemployee:
            labelemployee[employee].destroy()
```

and it gives me this error:

```
TypeError: remove() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'
```

then I tried

```
"for name in tabs["Requests"]"
```

just to see if it works or not.  It still has the same error.  If someone can assist me with this hump and clear my confusion, please. Here is the complete code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

labelemployee={}
upper_tabs = ["Final", "Requests", "Control"]
tabs = {}

class Application(ttk.Frame): #inherent from frame.

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg="LightBlue4")
        self.parent = parent
        self.Employees = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
        self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
        self.GUI()

    def GUI(self): #the function that runs all the GUI functions.
        self.create_tabs()
        self.buttons("Control")
        for name in upper_tabs[:2]:
        self.create_grid(name)
        self.add_left_names("Requests")
        self.add_left_names("Final")

    def create_tabs(self):
        self.tabControl = ttk.Notebook(self, width=1000, height=400)
        for name in upper_tabs:
            self.tab=tk.Frame(self.tabControl, bg='thistle')
            self.tabControl.add(self.tab, text=name)
            tabs[name] = self.tab
            self.tabControl.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')   

    def create_grid(self, name):
        for i in range (7):
            for j in range(7):
                self.label = tk.Label(tabs[name], relief="ridge", 
                     width=12, height=3)
                self.label.grid(row=i, column=j, sticky='nsew')

    def buttons(self, name):
        self.button=tk.Button(tabs[name], text="Clear", bg="salmon",   
            command = self.remove)
        self.button.pack()

    def add_left_names(self, name):
       #--------add in name labels on the side--------------        
        i=2
        for employee in self.Employees:
            self.label=tk.Label(tabs[name], text=employee ,  fg="red", 
               bg="snow")
            self.label.grid(row=i,column=0)
            labelemployee[employee]=self.label
            i +=1

    **def remove(self, name):
        for name in tabs[name]:
            for employee in labelemployee:
            labelemployee[employee].destroy()**

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("class basic window")
    root.geometry("1000x500")
    root.config(background="LightBlue4")
    app = Application(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to keep track of all the labels. Here just assigning the labels in *add_left_names* will override the previous label. So I stored the labels in a list which is the *value* to the employee *key*. Now in the remove function, you just need to iterate on all these labels in *labelemployee* and destroy them.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from collections import defaultdict

labelemployee=defaultdict(list)
upper_tabs = ["Final", "Requests", "Control"]
tabs = {}

class Application(ttk.Frame): #inherent from frame.

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, bg="LightBlue4")
        self.parent = parent
        self.Employees = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
        self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
        self.GUI()

    def GUI(self): #the function that runs all the GUI functions.
        self.create_tabs()
        self.buttons("Control")
        for name in upper_tabs[:2]:
            self.create_grid(name)
        self.add_left_names("Requests")
        self.add_left_names("Final")

    def create_tabs(self):
        self.tabControl = ttk.Notebook(self, width=1000, height=400)
        for name in upper_tabs:
            self.tab=tk.Frame(self.tabControl, bg='thistle')
            self.tabControl.add(self.tab, text=name)
            tabs[name] = self.tab
            self.tabControl.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')   

    def create_grid(self, name):
        for i in range (7):
            for j in range(7):
                self.label = tk.Label(tabs[name], relief="ridge", width=12, height=3)
                self.label.grid(row=i, column=j, sticky='nsew')

    def buttons(self, name):
        self.button=tk.Button(tabs[name], text="Clear", bg="salmon", command=self.remove)
        self.button.pack()

    def add_left_names(self, name):
       #--------add in name labels on the side--------------        
        i=2
        for employee in self.Employees:
            self.label=tk.Label(tabs[name], text=employee, fg="red", bg="snow")
            self.label.grid(row=i,column=0)
            labelemployee[employee].append(self.label)
            i +=1

    def remove(self):
        for employee in labelemployee:
            for label in labelemployee[employee]:
                label.destroy()

def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("class basic window")
    root.geometry("1000x500")
    root.config(background="LightBlue4")
    app = Application(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Hi @Miraj50, thanks again for your help.  this is first time I seen  defaultdict and I had to learn how it is implemented.  Just to confirm my learning, I have some  questions:  1.  labelemployee is a dictionary(defaultdict)? 2. the key is  [employee]? and the values are the memory location of each of the labels in different tabs of each employee? and 4, why didn't we use a regular dictionary? very much appreciate you time.

Comment: @fishtang A defaultdict is nothing special. Just that whenever you declare it, the variable automatically gets a default value. For e.g. here it will automatically be an empty list. So it would save me a line or two where I would have to manually check if the key was appearing for the first time then first initialize it with [] and then proceed.
Yes you are right. The value is a list of the widgets of that particular employee. So when you *clear*, I iterate through the list and destroy all of them.